# Airflow DAGS running fine with CLI but failing in airflow UI

Tags: airflow-2.x

I am new to Airflow, I have created a DAG that triggers the shell script, but I am able to run it and see the output from CLI but when I run it from the UI it is failing, Also, I am not able to see any logs,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have created a DAG and when I tested it from CLI it runs fine, When I try to run the same DAG from Airflow UI it fails and there are no logs to see the reason for being it failed,